# Downloading Large file from Mongodb using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I have stored more than 250MB zipped file in Mongodb using php. but i am unable to retrieve it back. It just shows me "0" number. Below is my code.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
require 'dbconnection.php';


$mongo = DBConnection::instantiate();
$gridFS = $mongo->database->getGridFS();

$object = $gridFS->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-type: '.$object->file['filetype']);
header('Expires: 0');


header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$object->file['filename']);
//header('Content-name: '.$object->file['filename']);
  header('Content-Type:application-x/force-download'); 
echo $object->getBytes();
```

Check it. This works fine for file less than 100MB.

Comment: Its most likely related to using up all available allowed memory.

Answer (score 2):

Read the docs, http://php.net/manual/en/mongogridfsfile.getbytes.php

> Warning: this will load the file into memory. If the file is bigger
>   than your memory, this will cause problems!

So you would need to store large files in chunks and then loop through and echo the chunks, I scoured google and found this (3. Shows how to access files based on chunks):

http://blog.hardkap.com/index.php/posts/00069/MongoDB---GridFS

Comment: Sorry i did get from the above link. The uploaded file of 254 MB has created a chunk size of 26 MB. While retrieving the file it will get a chunk one by one and download it. I don't think it will get the whole 254MB from the chunks to memory and then download it.